# CodeIgniter: View name different than Controller name, URL showing Controller's function name after POST instead of view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter v3.1.3

I have a Controller called User.php that mainly contains all of User management functions ( login, register, update_user, forgot_password, update_settings, ... )

And I have a View called Profile.php where on this view, two forms are available, one let's call it **Form1**, that updates the user info ( email, first_name, last_name ) and another, let's call it **Form2**, that updates the user settings ( news_letter_subscription, website_theme, allowed_countries_login ... )

**Form1** submits to *update_user* function in the User controller

**Form2** submits to *update_settings* function in the User controller

Whenever I submit one of these forms, after submitting, my URL becomes www.example.com/update_user or www.example.com/update_settings instead of staying www.example.com/profile ( since my view is called profile ).

My routes are the following:

```
$route['update_user']['POST'] = 'user/update_user';
$route['update_settings']['POST'] = 'user/update_settings';
```

My update_user function in the User.php controller:
http://pastebin.com/zQNn6Ykz

How can I make it that after the submission, the URL stays /profile and not /update_user or /update_settings ?

One thing you should know as well, I can't redirect to the profile page after the submission, as I'm using load->view since I'm passing data as well.

Thanks!

Edit: I can fix this problem by many other turnarounds, I could for instance make AJAX calls, or merge update_user and update_settings functions to one function called the same as the view, Profile() and send a hidden value with the action to take. But I'm honestly looking for a solution to fix my problem as it is, is it possible ?

Comment: show your controller function

Comment: This is my update_user function in the User.php controller: http://pastebin.com/zQNn6Ykz

Comment: first update_user and hide the update_settings after that you can try update_setting

Comment: Sorry could you further elaborate please ?

Comment: To server.com/profile? And that is the name of the view? Does that mean you have a `$route['profile']['POST'] = 'user/profile';` and a function `profile` that opens that view?

Comment: uncomment this two lin redirect('/profile?update=1', 'refresh');
                    redirect('/profile?update=0', 'refresh'); and check your code

Comment: This is the View function that I'm using: http://pastebin.com/6dEN1JQN
I have this function in a MY_Controller.php that it is extended in the User.php controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you are at server.com/profile, you save the form by calling another function in the same controller but still have the browser say you are at server.com/profile.

If that's the thing I can think of two ways to accomplish this.

The easy/hacky one would be to manipulate the history browser's object to change it with Javascript.

If you add this Javascript code in your profile view, every time it loads it will show the `new_url`. Change parameters accordingly.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Another solution would be to call /profile from every form. This would call the profile function in the User controller. In there you can check first what has been passed.

If there is a $_POST with data, you know you have to save first before showing the profile. Then it is just a matter of detecting which form was sent to call the proper function in the User controller (i.e. `$this->update_settings()`).

Comment: I had your second solution in mind, and was going to do that if no other solution was found. I think it's the best solution, but I prefer calling my functions something related to what they do, I"ll have to call the function Profile ( same as the view )

Comment: Well, it depends on how you look at it. Profile is not so far from what the function does. It loads the user's profile `$this->view('profile', $this->data);`. It is only one line of code in this function and for you the function does something else, but for the user that's what the function (URL interface) does. Seeing how CI maps URL with functions you have to decide which perspective you take to name your functions.

Comment: I kept thinking, would server.com/profile/save_settings be acceptable? I guess the answer is no, but if yes then you could route that to user/save_settings.

Comment: it wouldn't work, already tried that as well. The same thing would happen, the url will start showing /profile/save_settings

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden iframe with a name (for ex. my_iframe ) to your view (you need to add some css in order to hide it):

```
<iframe src="_blank" name="my_iframe"></iframe>
```

Then, put the "target" attribute to match you iframe name:

```
<form action="update_settings" method="post" target="my_iframe">
```

So, when you submit the form, it will do it in background. Maybe you need to use some javascript to retrieve the result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I could simply add hidden input called action something like that:
`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_user" >`

And post my form to a function called Profile in my User controller, and form the function check for that input and decide either to update profile or update settings. But I was looking for another way ?

Comment: @Lambasoft :) that was one of my suggestions.

Comment: When the submit event is triggered, the url will change necessarily... You can put the redirect (to go back to profile) after you finish the stuffs in user/update_user and user/update_settings